# celery: multiple import as failure

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I'm using celery as task runner. It's been working fine with Python 2.7. Recently I upgraded my PC to Ubuntu 16.04 and it starts to give met the following error:

```
from uuid import UUID, uuid4 as _uuid4, _uuid_generate_random
ImportError: cannot import name _uuid_generate_random
```

Full call stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/bin/celery", line 7, in <module>
    from celery.__main__ import main
  File "venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from celery import five  # noqa
  File "venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/five.py", line 153, in <module>
    from kombu.utils.compat import OrderedDict  # noqa
  File "venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from uuid import UUID, uuid4 as _uuid4, _uuid_generate_random
ImportError: cannot import name _uuid_generate_random
```

This seems rather strange to me. Currently my python version is:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

Was there some syntax change within the 2.7.x versions?

Comment: It looks like you're importing a "private" member (`_uuid_generate_random`).  You probably shouldn't do this as they could change without any notice between versions...

Comment: This isn't a SyntaxError, but an ImportError. So it's probably an issue with trying to import from the library, not with the syntax.

Comment: ah. don't I feel silly.

Answer (score 1):

`_uuid_generate_random` has been removed and `os.urandom` is used instead.

https://hg.python.org/releases/2.7.11/rev/24bdc4940e81

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in an old version of kombu. Just upgrade and the error should go away.

```
pip install -U kombu
```